# Stuck at the Xcode 12 build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, build, xcode12

I've stable code and its working fine for last version Xcode 11, I just updated OS and Xcode but now Xcode throwing error ***The Xcode build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace.*** and also ***Command ProcessPCH failed with a nonzero exit code***
I googled and did following steps.

- Deintegrate pods, remove workspace delete pod.lock file and again install pods
- Delete drive data and clean and again start
- Quit Xcode and again open
- Finally restart OS

after all above steps I'm still facing same issue for Xcode 12.0.1
I don't know its Xcode issue or anything else but my code was working fine before update.

[image]
Looking for help if anyone face this issue

Comment: Same issue here. Did you resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked for Xcode 12.5 on MacOS Bug Sur.

Following are the steps:

Go to **file** -> **Workspace Settings...**

Then update Build System from **Use Shared Settings** to **New Build System** under **Per-User Workspace Settings** as shown in attachment.

[image]

I had ran it and worked fine.

After few runs I revered the changes back to Use Shared Settings. and it also started working.

Hope it might be helpful.